# Kivy Debugging Android: PermissionError[Errno 13]Permission denied: '/data/.notion-py'

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I have been having this bug for some days now.

[image]

I am trying to deploy a kivy app to android using Buildozer on windows subsystem for linux. One of the packages of the project is [this one](https://github.com/jamalex/notion-py). I am not sure what causes this error as I am quite new to this but after searching for possible solutions I wasn't able to solve my problem. I have edited my buildozer.spec file requriments as follows:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,requests,urllib3,idna,certifi,chardet,cached_property,notion-py
```

Regarding permissions:

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET,WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Can someone help me please?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that the error is about trying to write `/data/.notion-py`, and that is the name of a python module you have included, it sounds like that module is erroneously trying to write to a directory where it doesn't have permission. Why it's doing this is something you'll need to debug, perhaps it's an option you can change.

Comment: I see :) thanks for answering. Would it be possible to provide permission to write to that directory somehow?

Comment: I don't think so, not without root permissions.